# OKI scanner driver (okiscantool) cannot find pygtk in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: python, scanner, 21.10

I had the OKI scanner driver install in Ubuntu 18.04 before I upgraded to 21.10.  Now when I start `okiscantool` I get the message `ImportError: No module named pygtk`.

I see python3 installed as well as python2.

```
~$ dpkg -l '*python*' | grep ii
ii  libpython2-stdlib:amd64          2.7.18-3                        amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (Python2)
ii  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64       2.7.18-8build1                  amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64        2.7.18-8build1                  amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 2.7)
ii  libpython3-stdlib:amd64          3.9.4-1build1                   amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
ii  libpython3.9:amd64               3.9.7-2build1                   amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 3.9)
ii  libpython3.9-minimal:amd64       3.9.7-2build1                   amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.9)
ii  libpython3.9-stdlib:amd64        3.9.7-2build1                   amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.9)
ii  python-apt-common                2.2.1                           all          Python interface to libapt-pkg (locales)
ii  python-is-python2                2.7.18-9                        all          symlinks /usr/bin/python to the DEPRECATED python2
ii  python-matplotlib-data           3.3.4-1                         all          Python based plotting system (data package)
ii  python2                          2.7.18-3                        amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (Python2 version)
ii  python2-minimal                  2.7.18-3                        amd64        minimal subset of the Python2 language
ii  python2.7                        2.7.18-8build1                  amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
ii  python2.7-minimal                2.7.18-8build1                  amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  python3                          3.9.4-1build1                   amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
ii  python3-apport                   2.20.11-0ubuntu71               all          Python 3 library for Apport crash report handling
ii  python3-apt                      2.2.1                           amd64        Python 3 interface to libapt-pkg
ii  python3-aptdaemon                1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu36          all          Python 3 module for the server and client of aptdaemon
ii  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets    1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu36          all          Python 3 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an aptdaemon client
ii  python3-bcrypt                   3.1.7-4                         amd64        password hashing library for Python 3
ii  python3-blinker                  1.4+dfsg1-0.3ubuntu2            all          fast, simple object-to-object and broadcast signaling library
ii  python3-brlapi:amd64             6.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2               amd64        Braille display access via BRLTTY - Python3 bindings
ii  python3-cairo:amd64              1.16.2-4build2                  amd64        Python3 bindings for the Cairo vector graphics library
ii  python3-certifi                  2020.6.20-1                     all          root certificates for validating SSL certs and verifying TLS hosts (python3)
ii  python3-cffi-backend:amd64       1.14.6-1build1                  amd64        Foreign Function Interface for Python 3 calling C code - runtime
ii  python3-chardet                  4.0.0-1                         all          universal character encoding detector for Python3
ii  python3-click                    7.1.2-1                         all          Wrapper around optparse for command line utilities - Python 3.x
ii  python3-colorama                 0.4.4-1                         all          Cross-platform colored terminal text in Python - Python 3.x
ii  python3-commandnotfound          21.10.0                         all          Python 3 bindings for command-not-found.
ii  python3-cryptography             3.3.2-1                         amd64        Python library exposing cryptographic recipes and primitives (Python 3)
ii  python3-cups:amd64               2.0.1-4build1                   amd64        Python3 bindings for CUPS
ii  python3-cupshelpers              1.5.15-0ubuntu2                 all          Python utility modules around the CUPS printing system
ii  python3-cycler                   0.10.0-3                        all          composable kwarg iterator (Python 3)
ii  python3-dateutil                 2.8.1-6                         all          powerful extensions to the standard Python 3 datetime module
ii  python3-dbus                     1.2.16-5                        amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (Python 3 interface)
ii  python3-debconf                  1.5.77                          all          interact with debconf from Python 3
ii  python3-debian                   0.1.39ubuntu1                   all          Python 3 modules to work with Debian-related data formats
ii  python3-defer                    1.0.6-2.1                       all          Small framework for asynchronous programming (Python 3)
ii  python3-distro                   1.5.0-1                         all          Linux OS platform information API
ii  python3-distro-info              1.0                             all          information about distributions' releases (Python 3 module)
ii  python3-distupgrade              1:21.10.8                       all          manage release upgrades
ii  python3-fasteners                0.14.1-2                        all          provides useful locks - Python 3.x
ii  python3-future                   0.18.2-5                        all          Clean single-source support for Python 3 and 2 - Python 3.x
ii  python3-gdbm:amd64               3.9.7-1                         amd64        GNU dbm database support for Python 3.x
ii  python3-ges-1.0                  1.18.5-1                        all          Python bindings for the GES library
ii  python3-gi                       3.40.1-1build1                  amd64        Python 3 bindings for gobject-introspection libraries
ii  python3-gi-cairo                 3.40.1-1build1                  amd64        Python 3 Cairo bindings for the GObject library
ii  python3-gpg                      1.14.0-1ubuntu4                 amd64        Python interface to the GPGME GnuPG encryption library (Python 3)
ii  python3-gst-1.0                  1.18.5-1                        amd64        GStreamer GObject Introspection overrides for Python (Python 3)
ii  python3-httplib2                 0.18.1-3ubuntu1                 all          comprehensive HTTP client library written for Python3
ii  python3-ibus-1.0                 1.5.25-2build1                  all          Intelligent Input Bus - introspection overrides for Python (Python 3)
ii  python3-idna                     2.10-1                          all          Python IDNA2008 (RFC 5891) handling (Python 3)
ii  python3-importlib-metadata       4.0.1-1                         all          library to access the metadata for a Python package - Python 3.x
ii  python3-jeepney                  0.7.1-1                         all          pure Python D-Bus interface
ii  python3-jwt                      1.7.1-2ubuntu2                  all          Python 3 implementation of JSON Web Token
ii  python3-keyring                  23.0.1-1                        all          store and access your passwords safely
ii  python3-kiwisolver               1.3.1-1build1                   amd64        fast implementation of the Cassowary constraint solver - Python 3.X
ii  python3-launchpadlib             1.10.13-1                       all          Launchpad web services client library (Python 3)
ii  python3-lazr.restfulclient       0.14.2-2build1                  all          client for lazr.restful-based web services (Python 3)
ii  python3-lazr.uri                 1.0.5-1                         all          library for parsing, manipulating, and generating URIs
ii  python3-ldb                      2:2.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.2        amd64        Python 3 bindings for LDB
ii  python3-lib2to3                  3.9.7-1                         all          Interactive high-level object-oriented language (lib2to3)
ii  python3-lockfile                 1:0.12.2-2.2                    all          file locking library for Python — Python 3 library
ii  python3-louis                    3.18.0-1                        all          Python bindings for liblouis
ii  python3-macaroonbakery           1.3.1-1                         all          Higher-level macaroon operations for Python 3
ii  python3-mako                     1.1.3+ds1-2                     all          fast and lightweight templating for the Python 3 platform
ii  python3-markupsafe               1.1.1-1build2                   amd64        HTML/XHTML/XML string library for Python 3
ii  python3-matplotlib               3.3.4-1                         amd64        Python based plotting system in a style similar to Matlab (Python 3)
ii  python3-minimal                  3.9.4-1build1                   amd64        minimal subset of the Python language (default python3 version)
ii  python3-monotonic                1.5-3                           all          implementation of time.monotonic() - Python 3.x
ii  python3-more-itertools           4.2.0-3                         all          library with routines for operating on iterables, beyond itertools (Python 3)
ii  python3-nacl                     1.4.0-1build1                   amd64        Python bindings to libsodium (Python 3)
ii  python3-netifaces                0.10.9-0.2                      amd64        portable network interface information - Python 3.x
ii  python3-numpy                    1:1.19.5-1ubuntu2               amd64        Fast array facility to the Python 3 language
ii  python3-oauthlib                 3.1.0-2                         all          generic, spec-compliant implementation of OAuth for Python3
ii  python3-olefile                  0.46-3                          all          Python module to read/write MS OLE2 files
ii  python3-paramiko                 2.7.2-1ubuntu1                  all          Make ssh v2 connections (Python 3)
ii  python3-pexpect                  4.8.0-2ubuntu1                  all          Python 3 module for automating interactive applications
ii  python3-pil:amd64                8.1.2+dfsg-0.3ubuntu0.1         amd64        Python Imaging Library (Python3)
ii  python3-pkg-resources            52.0.0-4                        all          Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
ii  python3-problem-report           2.20.11-0ubuntu71               all          Python 3 library to handle problem reports
ii  python3-protobuf                 3.12.4-1ubuntu3                 amd64        Python 3 bindings for protocol buffers
ii  python3-ptyprocess               0.7.0-1                         all          Run a subprocess in a pseudo terminal from Python 3
ii  python3-pyatspi                  2.38.1-1                        all          Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface - Python3 bindings
ii  python3-pymacaroons              0.13.0-4                        all          Macaroon library for Python 3
ii  python3-pyparsing                2.4.7-1                         all          alternative to creating and executing simple grammars - Python 3.x
ii  python3-renderpm:amd64           3.5.66-1                        amd64        python low level render interface
ii  python3-reportlab                3.5.66-1                        all          ReportLab library to create PDF documents using Python3
ii  python3-reportlab-accel:amd64    3.5.66-1                        amd64        C coded extension accelerator for the ReportLab Toolkit
ii  python3-requests                 2.25.1+dfsg-2                   all          elegant and simple HTTP library for Python3, built for human beings
ii  python3-rfc3339                  1.1-2                           all          parser and generator of RFC 3339-compliant timestamps (Python 3)
ii  python3-samba                    2:4.13.14+dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.10.4 amd64        Python 3 bindings for Samba
ii  python3-secretstorage            3.3.1-1                         all          Python module for storing secrets - Python 3.x version
ii  python3-simplejson               3.17.2-1                        amd64        simple, fast, extensible JSON encoder/decoder for Python 3.x
ii  python3-six                      1.16.0-2                        all          Python 2 and 3 compatibility library (Python 3 interface)
ii  python3-software-properties      0.99.13.1                       all          manage the repositories that you install software from
ii  python3-speechd                  0.10.2-2build1                  all          Python interface to Speech Dispatcher
ii  python3-sss                      2.4.1-2ubuntu4                  amd64        Python3 module for the System Security Services Daemon
ii  python3-systemd                  234-3build4                     amd64        Python 3 bindings for systemd
ii  python3-talloc:amd64             2.3.1-2ubuntu2                  amd64        hierarchical pool based memory allocator - Python3 bindings
ii  python3-tdb                      1.4.3-1build1                   amd64        Python3 bindings for TDB
ii  python3-tk:amd64                 3.9.7-1                         amd64        Tkinter - Writing Tk applications with Python 3.x
ii  python3-tz                       2021.1-1                        all          Python3 version of the Olson timezone database
ii  python3-uno                      1:7.2.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1        amd64        Python-UNO bridge
ii  python3-update-manager           1:21.10.5                       all          python 3.x module for update-manager
ii  python3-urllib3                  1.26.5-1~exp1                   all          HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling for Python3
ii  python3-wadllib                  1.3.5-1                         all          Python 3 library for navigating WADL files
ii  python3-xdg                      0.27-2                          all          Python 3 library to access freedesktop.org standards
ii  python3-xkit                     0.5.0ubuntu4                    all          library for the manipulation of xorg.conf files (Python 3)
ii  python3-yaml                     5.3.1-5                         amd64        YAML parser and emitter for Python3
ii  python3-zipp                     1.0.0-3                         all          pathlib-compatible Zipfile object wrapper - Python 3.x
ii  python3.9                        3.9.7-2build1                   amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.9)
ii  python3.9-minimal                3.9.7-2build1                   amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.9)
```

I'm not a python hacker, so can someone please tell me how to get pygtk to be activated or registered again?

Comment: Are you using this driver(okimfpsdrv_1.7-0_amd64_231225.deb)? Scanner drivers OKI multifunctional printers  https://www.oki.com/ru/printing/download/okimfpsdrv_1.7-0_amd64_231225.deb

Comment: Yes, @JohanPalych, those are the drivers I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can install `python-gtk2` by manual download using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

and then retry launching `okiscantool`.

Comment: I installed the packages you listed and `okiscantool` now works again!